# Plot points around circumference of circle in 3D space given 3 points

Tags: calculus, circles, spherical-coordinates

I have a problem relative to robotics where I would like to teach 3 Cartesian points in 3D space that define a circle and then find a number of way-points along that circle to execute - for example move to a point every 3 degrees along the circle between the first point and the third point.  I can define points A,B & C.  From those 3 points in space I know how to calculate the center of the circle (point D) and the radius. My thought is that I would then shift points A & C relative to the origin and then convert them to spherical coordinates using:

```
R=x2+y2+z2
θ=cos−1(zR)
ϕ=tan−1(yx)
```

I might then define a great circle from points A & C but I'm uncertain how to calculate the way-points between them along the arc every 3 degrees for example. Once I have the spherical coordinates for the waypoints I would then convert them back to cartisian and shift them back to point D.  I would like to ask if anyone can give me some direction on how to calculate points every (x) degrees between the two points on the great circle and also if I have the right approach on how to accomplish this.

I appreciate the assistance.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULRmL.png):

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, given the points $A, B, C,$ the center $D$, and the radius $R$:

Compute the vector $\mathbf v = A - D,$ that is, a vector of length $R$ in the direction from $D$ to $A.$

Compute the vector $\mathbf u = B - D.$ If $\mathbf u$ would be in the opposite direction from $\mathbf v,$ then set $\mathbf u = C - D$ instead.

Project $\mathbf u$ onto $\mathbf v.$ Let the projected vector be
$\mathbf u_\parallel.$
The formula to compute this is
$$
\mathbf u_\parallel = 
\left(\frac{\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v}{\lVert\mathbf v \rVert^2}\right)
\mathbf v.
$$

Let $\mathbf u_\perp = \mathbf u - \mathbf u_\parallel.$

Then $\mathbf u_\perp$ is in the plane of the circle and is perpendicular to
$\mathbf v.$
Let $\mathbf w = \frac{R}{\lVert\mathbf u_\perp\rVert} \mathbf u_\perp,$
that is, $\mathbf w$ is a vector of length $R$ in the same direction as
$\mathbf u_\perp.$
Now you have two perpendicular vectors of length $R$ in the plane of the circle.

Alternatively, use some other method to get perpendicular vectors $\mathbf v$
and $\mathbf w$ of length $R$ in the plane of the circle.
There are various ways.

Once you have the vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w,$
to generate a point $P$ on the circle simply choose an angle $\theta$ and let
$$ P = D + (\cos\theta)\mathbf v + (\sin\theta)\mathbf w.$$

You can get points at intervals of $x$ degrees by adding $x$ to the angle repeatedly.

Comment: thank you for the response,  I will start studying projecting vectors - im not familiar with this (yet).  Please let me know if you know of any basic examples I can follow.  thank you again for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: I've added the formula for the projection. One of the alternative methods is to use cross-products instead of projection.

Comment: thank you very much.  On a slightly different topic - I was also contemplating if converting to spherical coordinates is the most straightforward way to accomplish this.  I've seen a few topics where it is suggested that the points around the circumference first be calculated on a 2D plane using: [X = r * cosine(angle),  Y = r * sine(angle)] and then converting those points from  the 2D plane into the 3D coordinate system.  this of course would also be a learning curve for me in converting from a 2D plane at some given angle into 3D but curious if that type of method would be simpler.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just answered another question on the 2D-3D coordinate conversions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007739/transformation-matrix-between-a-2d-and-a-3d-coordinate-system. You still need to be able to identify some vectors in the 3D space that are similar to the vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ I used here. Basically, a circle with an arbitrary center at an arbitrary orientation requires you to figure out a bunch of coordinates in order to describe its center and 2D plane.

Comment: I just read through your post - thats great info and exactly what I was curious about.  It appears that using spherical coordinates as planned would be of similar complexity and perhaps more straightforward than trying to convert a 2D plane into a 3D coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to follow

- find the center of the circle (you have this), say it's a vector $\vec D$
- move points A, B, C towards the origin. $\vec {A'}=\vec A-\vec D$ and so on.
- calculate the axis of rotation, using cross product $$\vec n=\frac{\vec{A'}\times\vec{B'}}{|\vec{A'}\times\vec{B'}|}$$
- rotate $\vec{A'}$ by an angle $\theta$ around $\vec n$. You can use matrix multiplication. You can find the formula for the rotation matrix on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)
  $$\vec{P'}=R_n(\theta)\vec{A'}$$
- move $\vec{P'}$ back to the original circle $$\vec{P}=\vec{P'}+\vec{D}$$